# Ruby Regex Different from Rubular

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

I'm trying the same super simple regex on Rubular.com and my VM Linux with Ruby 1.9.2 I dont' know why I'm getting different outputs: 
VM:

```
my_str = "Madam Anita"
puts my_str[/\w/]
```

this Outputs: Madam

on Rubular it outputs: MadamAnita
Rubular: 
http://www.rubular.com/r/qyQipItdes

I would love some help. I stuck here. I will not be able to test my code for the hw1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't really. It matches all characters in "Madam" and "Anita", but not the space. The problem you are having is that `my_str[/\w/]` only returns a single match for the given regular expression, whereas Rubular highlights all possible matches.

If you need all occurrences, you could do this:

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > "Madam Anita".scan(/\w+/)
 => ["Madam", "", "Anita", ""]
```

Comment: Use `\w+` instead...empty groups are usually not so useful.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `\w` matches *a single character*. The result in Rubular contains spaces between adjacent characters to tell you this (though I wish they'd also make the highlighting more obvious...). Compare with the output from matching [`\w+`](http://www.rubular.com/r/rZ8Bdfj3xp), which matches two strings (`Madam` and `Anita`).

Comment: thanks for notice this out. I would like a better highlighting also.